# How to include PostgreSQL functions in Django migrations?

Tags: django, postgresql

I would like to include some PostgreSQL functions as part of the database migration.

The two ways I can see are:

1. Editing the migrations file (generated by `python manage.py makemigrations`)
2. Hooking post table creation

The first seems easier, but laborious if the migration needs to be remade. What would you recommend the best way to go about it?

Comment: Why would the migration need to be remade?

Comment: You shouldn't edit migrations created by `makemigrations`, usually. But nothing stops you from adding your own migration (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/writing-migrations/)) with your own `RunSQL` commands, which will just be run as any other migration.

Comment: Thanks both.@RemcoGerlich in case the model is modified -- is there a better way to do that? @dirkgroten TIL I'll give that a go!

Comment: If a model is modified a new migration will be made, the old file won't be modified. I agree that this should be put in a new migration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answering my own question to clear up the question (thanks to all the comments):

First I made an empty migration (`python manage.py makemigrations --empty app_name`)

Then, to operations add the function's SQL:

```
migrations.RunSQL(
    ('CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function() ...'),
    ('DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS my_function();')
)
```

The two lines are for migrate and unmigrate SQL, read more here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/migration-operations/#runsql

The custom migration will be run automatically after the main migrations.